# Spring Batch Admin

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I want to add a new menu to spring batch admin,
I have gone through the docs but not helpful, can anyone please help me with an example also where to put FTL files for that menu.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is far too open ended.
[HERE](http://ursvik.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-extend-spring-batch-admin-with.html) is an example of how to customize spring-batch admin.

Be advised that spring batch admin is at end of life and the last milestone release has quite a few issues in its POM dependencies.  You'll need liberal use of maven exclude elements to get it to compile without a ton of dependency conflicts.

[End Of Life Announcement](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/trunk/)

Per the above you should look into "Spring Cloud Data Flow" instead of spring-batch-admin.  I have not used this yet, but the maven issues in the milestone release were a huge pain.  Honestly I never did get it to work the way I wanted.

All that said your FTL files go in the webapp/WEB-INF/web directory tree.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

To add a menu in SBA, you need to develop following components:

> > A class that extends the BaseMenu (Class implementing the SBA menu interface).
> >
> > A Controller class handling the request issued on click of you menu
> >
> > A View bean
> >
> > A Freemarker template implementing the view.

Template files are looked at WEB-INF/web. Place your template file under WEB-INF/web/ftl.